# access the value of minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters in the membership config using c#

Tags: c#, membership

I want to give an error message if someone tries to create a password with too few alpha numeric characters. I want to show how many none alpha numeric characters to use. This defined in the web.config under membership with property minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacter. As this can change and I dont want to hard code the number in the error message how can I get to this value. I dont seem to be able to do this with configurationManager.

Any thoughts?

thanks
Andy

Comment: Have you already tried the [MembershipProvider.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.minrequirednonalphanumericcharacters.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
```